# Linear subspaces of projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, morphism

I'm following a basic course in Algebraic Geometry where the lectures are based on the first chapter of *Algebraic Geometry*  by Robin Hartshorne. Our lecturer gave an additional advanced exercise after the first three sections. I don't really have a clue how to start off with it.

Let $k<n$ be natural numbers. Suppose that $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$ are linear subspaces of dimension $k$ and $n-k-1$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over an algebraically closed field. Moreover, suppose that $\Lambda \cap \Gamma = \emptyset$.

1. Show that for each $Q \in \mathbb{P}^n\setminus \Lambda$ the intersection of $<Q,\Lambda>$ and $\Gamma$ has only one point $\pi(Q)$. Here $<Q,\Lambda>$ is the union of all projective lines $\mathbb{P}^1\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ connecting points in $\Lambda$ with $Q$.
2. Show that $\pi$ is a morphism.
3. Let $\Theta$ be  a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and  $\Lambda \cap \Theta= \emptyset$. Is $\pi(\Theta)$ a linear subspace of $\Gamma$?
4. The same question as (3) but without the condition that $\Lambda \cap \Theta= \emptyset$.

Does anybody have some hints, references or answers that could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the trick here should be to write down everything explicitly in coordinates.Let's call the field of definition $K$.

1. Let's fix coordinates $x_0,\dots x_n$ for $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let's suppose $\Lambda=\{x_{n-k}=\dots x_n=0 \}$ and $\Gamma=\{x_0=\dots x_{n-k-1}=0\}$. Now $Q \in \mathbb{P}^n-\Lambda$ so that this point has  $x_{i} \neq 0$ with $n-k \leq i \leq n$. Now, we have $Q=[q_0 : \dots q_n]$. So we have $ Span(Q,\Lambda)=[\lambda q_0+ \mu x_0 \dots \lambda q_{n-k-1}+\mu x_{n-k-1} : \lambda q_{n-k} \dots \lambda q_n]$ with $x_i \in K$ and $\lambda \neq 0$.

So, when we do $Span(Q,\Lambda ) \cap \Gamma $ what we get is $[0 : \dots 0: q_{n-k} : \dots q_n]$. Note that this tells you also that the projection you have just defined is also a morphism, so that we get free 2.

3.Now, let's call $p: K^{n+1}-0 \to \mathbb{P}^n$ your standard projection. Let's call $W \subset K^{n+1}$ the vectorial subspace such that $p(W)=\Theta$ , $V $ the one such that $p(V)=\Lambda$ and $Z$ the one  such that $p(Z)=\Gamma$. The condition on the intersection is nothing else that $V$ is in direct sum with $W$.We also have $V \oplus Z=K^{n+1}$. Let's call $\phi:K^{n+1} \to Z$ the projection induced by such a decomposition. As you can check, the morphism $\pi$ one defines is such that $\pi(p)=p(\phi)$ (where everything is defined !) so that one gets also $\pi(p(W))$ is $p(\phi(W))$ and so a vectorial subspace.

4. I'm assuming that this question is referred to $\pi(\Theta)$ as the image of the points where $\pi$ is defined. So now let's take $n=2$, $\Lambda=\{x_0=x_1=0\}$ and $\Gamma=\{x_2=0\}$. Let $\Theta=\{x_1=x_2=0\}$: we get $\pi(\Theta)=[x_0 : 0 : 0 ]$ with $x_0 \neq 0$ that is not a subspace.